# When are the Wardstone chronicles set?

Tags: wardstone-chronicles

I'm in the middle of reading *The Spook's Curse* again and there are several historical features mentioned that ought to be able to determine when this is set.  The average lifespan according to the Bane is 20-30 years, which suggests that this is occurring prior to the scientific revolution, and there are witch-hunts occurring.  Does anyone know the time period when the Wardstone Chronicles are actually set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Word of God](http://www.spooksworld.co.uk/Questions.aspx) is that the book series isn't set in a *specific* time period but that the 'County' is roughly based on 17th Century Lancashire.

> **Alice :** *Mr. Delaney, Do you think setting the book in the seventeenth century makes it spookier?*
>
> **Joseph Delaney :** *It is not the 17th century – I never mention dates.*

and

> **Rebecca :** *What year are the spooks books set in?*
>
> **Joseph Delaney :** *I have set my tales in a mythical Lancashire so historical dates are not relevant. But if you had to select a time
>   period the 17th Century would be the best choice.*

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering the same thing too.

With careful examination of the first four books we find too many anachronisms to place the books in any specific time period.  It narrows it down mostly to the 17th century but there are things that shouldn't exist together

Shire horse-term first used in mid 17th century.

Catholic Church- okay so the books don't use the word catholic but the church and society at priest town are show a more or less catholic church.  The English Reformation was in the 16th century.

Thoroughbred Horses-term was first used at the beginning of the 18th century.

Red coats for the army-while the Yeoman guard has had red coats for longer the official adoption of the red coat was in 1645 for the New Model Army (17th century)

The Cannon-this bit of Technology could push the story back as far as the 14th century. There's also a distinct lack of guns (they may show up later in the series as I said I'm only looking at books 1-4) but it would seem that the soldiers should have them as 17th century uniforms got rid of armor and muskets and some civilian rifles were now a part of marksmanship.

Village school-public grammar schools were organized into a national system under Edward VI in the mid 16th century, but private/charitable ones were available before that even.

As I said most things point to 17th century but the presence of the catholic church says it can't take place after the 16th century while Thoroughbred horses say it can't be before the 18th century.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much earlier than the 17th century. I am thinking it is closer to the 11th century, and leading to the battle at Hastings (ie 1066)..  My reasons for this is the lack of technology: no clock towers, few of any paved roads, all the books are hand copied, there is no whale oil or products from whales which was started being used in the 16th century.

There has been other invaders after that time, but the invaders coming from the south reads France in my opinion and the French did that invade in the 14th century had no battles on English land.

Comment: Interesting conjecture, but the above answer provides information from the author who is probably the best authority in this case!  I appreciate your effort though :D

Answer (score 0):

If I were to place a time on the books, I too would say in the 17th century. Personally, I’d go for very early, around 1610, for the beginning of the series. The famous Pendle witch trials were held in 1612, in Lancashire, which are mentioned in the book, I believe. Is it all too much of a coincidence that witches of Pendle Hill were said to be killed around early 17th century, where the author himself also gives a small hint to this time? I think not.

There are also references to Demdike in the book, who was killed in the witch trials- Elizabeth Southerns. Either way, if anyone can find better connections, I think the witch trials of 1612 are definitely mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 0):

It’s almost official. The Spooks Battle is set roughly 1615. Look at this quote-

> “The magistrate's name is Roger Nowell and until about five years ago he was High Sheriff at Caster. He's an esquire, one rank below a knight, and also a good, honest man.”

If Roger Nowell was a real person and was magistrate at the Pendle Witch trials in 1612 and onwards. He was high Sheriff until around 1610. Also, about this time there were lots of accusations against the Pendle Witches.

Answer (score 0):

There’s references to a massive civil war in the first book, but the red uniforms definitely sets it later than the war of the roses, Joseph Delaney has also gone on record saying the story takes place some time in the late 17th century, meaning after the 30 years war, which was also the catalyst for a renewed round of witch hunts. In book 4, however, there is a big reference to an invasion of the British Isles, a contested one at that, meaning it was not the Glorious Revolution of 1688 where the Dutch took over the monarchy to make it Protestant again, but most likely the Second Anglo-Dutch War, setting the actual invasion of the isles in 1667 when the Dutch sailed up the Thames and engaged several forts and captured the HMS Royal Charles. Tom also gets temporarily kidnapped by a press gang in book 5, a few months after the events of book 4.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as quotes or passages from the relevant books, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).